# Why is a forward slash in the URL causing an infinite loop of calls to my Stripes Action Bean?

Tags: java, stripes

I have implemented a website based on Stripes. I want to avoid using the .action appendix to its URLs. In each of my Action Beans, I have added url bindings of the type : `@URLBinding("/home")`.

Then, in my web.xml I have configured the DynamicMappingFilter, as described in http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/DynamicMappingFilter.html.

The site is live, and running fine... Except when someone tries a url like http://example.com/home/anything. This causes an infinite loop call to my HomeActionBean, until finally I get a StackOverflowError!

Did anyone experience the same thing, and do you know how to prevent this from happening?

Thanks a lot.
Eduardo

P.S. Here are some details about the implementation. I have created a demo, with a simple Test action bean and JSP.

```
TestActionBean
    @UrlBinding("/test")
public class TestActionBean extends BaseActionBean implements ActionBean {

@DefaultHandler
public Resolution test() {
    return new ForwardResolution("test.jsp");
}
}
```

Test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test infinite loop</title>
</head>
<body>
blabla
</body>
</html>`
```

WEB.XML

```
<filter>
    <display-name>Stripes Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
          <param-value>pt.company.commons.stripes.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ActionBeanContext.Class</param-name>
        <param-value>pt.company.commons.stripes.action.CustomActionBeanContext</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- The parameter tells Stripes to use the Spring interceptor -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Interceptor.Classes</param-name>
          <param-value>net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring.SpringInterceptor</param-value>
    </init-param>
...

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <description>Dynamically maps URLs to ActionBeans.</description>
    <display-name>Stripes Dynamic Mapping Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>DynamicMappingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DynamicMappingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
        <param-value>pt.company.common.stripes.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>DynamicMappingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't give an explanation for this behaviour but I noticed it once on an actionBean that showed a page containing iframes having a relative path as their src attribute. The src attributes themselves point to other actions beans.

```
        <iframe src="imagelist"></iframe>
        <iframe src="mastertable/collections"></iframe>
```

Once I changed to absolute paths, redirect loops were gone.

```
        <iframe src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/imagelist"></iframe>
        <iframe src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mastertable/collections"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hey Richard - Thanks. But I have actually just created a demo action bean, with a simple forward to an empty test.jsp, and I get exactly the same behaviour - infinite loops if I use a http://example.com/test/smth url.

Comment: I have just added the test code as an edit to my original post. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think the problem is in the ForwardResolution. When test.jsp resides in the ROOT it should read `return new ForwardResolution("/test.jsp");` Notice the forward slash.

Comment: BTW I usually keep jsp files in a folder /WEB-INF/jsp then link to that folder /WEB_INF/jsp/test.jsp, also starting with a forward slash from root.